# How to send a simple UDP message from my local computer(client.py) to a remote server pythonanywhere(server.py)

Tags: python, sockets, server, udp, portforwarding

I want to send a simple UDP message from my local computer(client.py) to a remote server pythonanywhere(server.py). I don't actually know if I'm doing it right, or maybe what I did is not a good practice. How can I do that? I'm still a beginner in socket programming.

client.py(local computer)

```
import socket

ip = "<insert ip here>"
port = 9999
Message = "Hello, Server"

clientSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
clientSock.sendto(Message.encode('utf-8'), (ip, port))
```

server.py(pythonanywhere)

```
import socket

ip = "<insert ip here>"
port = 9999

serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

serverSock.bind((ip, port))

while True:
    data, addr = serverSock.recvfrom(4096)
    print("Message: ", data)
```

Comment: Try `serverSock.bind(("", port))`. If your computer has multiple network interfaces then you may need to specify one vs the other. You can verify `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` returns the IP address you expect on the server.

Comment: but the ```socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())``` returns as ```127.0.0.1```

Comment: localhost probably the first network interface. Does serverSock.bind(("", port)) work with your client?

Comment: nope, sorry ;-;

Comment: welp im going to delete this soon because im going to try it on flask later :>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234588/discussion-between-dunno-dotcom-and-jasonm1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a udp socket server on PythonAnywhere. PythonAnywhere does not route arbitrary network traffic to the machines where you would be running the server code.

Comment: I see, no wonder why they give me localhost. Thank you :)

although this time, I'm deploying a flask webapp in pythonanywhere to send requests. My goal actually, is to send some data to the server. So maybe http server would do I guess.

Comment: Question? Is there any way to host a udp socket server, then the client/s send something to the udp socket server. Something like a streaming server?